# Handshake failure when trying to push repository to bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I am trying to push my Mercurial repository to Bitbucket using `hg push <web address of my repo on bitbucket>` and am getting:

> abort: error: _ssl.c:507: error:14094410:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

This only started happening after I updated Yosemite 10.10.1 (which I think is only available for developers).

Does anyone have any clue of how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Mercurial 2.7 or 2.7.1 (time to upgrade!), you can experience this issue.
It's a bug causing Mercurial to only try SSLv3, instead of other options. If the server doesn't have SSLv3 (perhaps Bitbucket doesn't have this), the push will fail.

[More details here...](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Mercurial-amp-SSL-amp-POODLE-Mercurial-2-7-and-2-7-1-and-SSL-error-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-td4014939.html)

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded and it fixed the problem.